# How to re size image using PHP, how to remove the error 500 Internal Server Error 817ms

Tags: php, php-5.2

I am doing one file upload in PHP. From here user uploads the large image means, I want to re size the image. I am writing like this but i can't get an answer. I am getting an error like this **500 Internal Server Error x
        817ms**. After the resizing occurs on the image I want to encode that value, how can I do this?

```js
$.ajax({
  formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
        url: 'file_check.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
        var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
        console.log(res);
         
        },
       });

file_check.php


<?php
/*$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$path = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = file_get_contents($path);*/
/*    
$imgdata = base64_encode($im); // here we got base64 encode value

$idproof = array("encode" => $imgdata,
                 "path" =>$path,
                 "extension" =>$extension,
                 );
echo json_encode($idproof);*/

   
   $image;
   $image_type;

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Load Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function load($filename) 
   {
       global $image;
       global $image_type;

            $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
            $image_type = $image_info[2];
            if($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            } 
            elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            }
            elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) 
            {
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Save Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null)
   {
       global $image;
       global $image_type;

            if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) 
            {
                imagejpeg($image,$filename,$compression);
            }
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )
            {
                imagegif($image,$filename);
            } 
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG )
            {
                imagepng($image,$filename);
            }
            if( $permissions != null ) 
            {
                chmod($filename,$permissions);
            }
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   View Image file
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
   {
      global $image;
      global $image_type;

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG )
      {
         imagejpeg($image);
      } 
      elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )
      {
         imagegif($image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) 
      {
         imagepng($image);
      }
   }

   function getWidth() 
   {
      global $image;
      return imagesx($image);
   }
   function getHeight() 
   {
      global $image;
      return imagesy($image);
   }

   //=============================================================================
   //   Resize Images
   //=============================================================================

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 01 - Resize to Height
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resizeToHeight($height) 
   {
      $ratio = $height / getHeight();
      $width = getWidth() * $ratio;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 02 - Resize to Width
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resizeToWidth($width) 
   {
      $ratio = $width / getWidth();
      $height = getheight() * $ratio;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 03 - Scale in %
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function scale($scale) 
   {
      $width = getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = getheight() * $scale/100;
      resize($width,$height);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------
   //   Resize Images 04 - Scale in %
   //-----------------------------------------------
   function resize($width,$height) 
   {
      global $image;

      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, getWidth(), getHeight());
      $image = $new_image;
   }     


echo load($_FILES['IMAGE_FILE']['tmp_name']);

// To resize based on image width
echo resizeToWidth($width); 

// To resize based on image height
echo resizeToHeight($height); 

// To resize to specific size
echo resize($width, $height) 

echo output();

$filename = base64_encode(output());

$idproof = array("encode" => $filename,
                 );
echo json_encode($idproof);


?>
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="idproof" name="myForm">
<div class="input-group heading1">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                  Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="myFile" name="file" >
              </span>
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
  <div class="input-group heading1">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md horoscope">Upload ID Proof</button>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
</form
```

Comment: need to see the error that you get, instead of internal 500 error, that is too common, put these to your php code: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Off topic, but I recommend moving the PHP bits out of your main JavaScript file, so that the rest of the JS code can be static so you can save server resources and so the file can be cached by the browser.